# sed delete lines matching pattern between 2 files

Tags: awk, sed

Hey i'm still a beginner on sed and i'm trying to sed script to only output the lines not found of 1.txt to 2.txt if the line has the /pattern/ . I have the following :

```
1.txt
demo@example.de:boo
demo2@example.com:foo
demo3@example.nl:foo

2.txt
@example.de
@example.com
```

The desired output would be

```
demo3@example.nl:foo
```

I've tryed those commands looks not working

```
$ grep -f 2.txt 1.txt
$ cat 2.txt | xargs -I {} sed -n "/{}/p" 1.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using following awk command.

```
awk -F '[@:]' 'NR == FNR { blacklist[$2]; next } !($2 in blacklist)' 2.txt 1.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F '[@:]'` tells awk that fields in input lines are separated by a `@` or `:`. (`demo@example.com:foo` -> `$1 = demo`, `$2 = example.com`, `$3 = foo`)
- `NR == FNR <action>` means do the following action only while processing the first file given as an argument to awk.
- `blacklist[$2]` registers a key in array `blacklist` with the domain name in the current line.
- `next` means skip to next line.
- `!($2 in blacklist)` means print the current line if the domain name in it does not exist in array `blacklist`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-v` option of `grep`, no need to use `sed`:

```
grep -vFf 2.txt 1.txt
```

```
demo3@example.nl:foo
```

Comment: A better option might be to use `w` instead of `F` otherwise `example.com` could match `example.company.de`

Comment: just noticed the same. I did the test without the `@`. The `@` breaks the usage of `-w`